# Can I tell .net's Intellisense how to sort fields?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, intellisense, class-design, decorator

In Visual Studio, Intellisense sorts the fields of an object by alphabetical order. I am used to Delphi, where Intellisense sorts by (method, property, event) and then alphabetically.

Is there a decoration once can add to a class/struct definition to tell Intellisense how to sort fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot. It's [a feature that's been requested](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=114373&wa=wsignin1.0) but just hasn't made it in yet.