# How to display intellisense's suggestions in the order they are defined?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

For example i've been created a struct

```
struct man
{
    public int age;
    public bool sex;
    public float growth;
}
```

And when in code I'm start typing something like this:

```
static void GetSex(man Joe)
{
    int age = Joe.
}
```

It gives me variants sorted by name. Like this

```
age
growth
sex
```

But how can I make visual studio not to sort by name? And give list like this

```
age
sex
growth
```

Like I wrote it in order i want.

Comment: Visual Studio does not sort "internally". What you (probably) see is the IntelliSense, which sorts your fields but that's just for quickly finding what you're looking for

Comment: you can ask this question to visual studio devlopers

Comment: Questions about help with common software tools are ontopic here, I fail to see what warrants the downvotes.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, downvotes are not the same a flags. I think people just consider this a bad question but there's no "appropriate" flag for this.

Comment: This is not appropriate here. And you cannot do this.

Comment: There is nothing inappropriate in this question as far as I can tell. I have given it a clearer title though.

Comment: It's certainly an improvement :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I tell .net's Intellisense how to sort fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116688/can-i-tell-nets-intellisense-how-to-sort-fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the Visual Studio "IntelliSense" feature. You can find settings for it under the "Tools / Options" menu, but there are very few.

You can choose what displays in the list, which key(s) selects the highlighted item, and how the first highlighted item is selected, but there's nothing available that would allow you to reorder the items.

[image]

Comment: I don't see that option in vs 2019, do you know where I can find it?